# What is the difference between c++, objective-c and objective-c++?

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I want to know the difference between c++ and objective-c and objective-c++.
Can any one give me the difference and Can we use the c++ for iPhone development

Thank you,
Madan Mohan

Comment: Objective-C++?! I've never heard about it. Pure C++ `is` objective, so I don't see any reason for Obj-C++ to exist. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @rhino: Objective-C++ is simply Objective-C (and its frameworks) with C++ code. Pure C++ is not objective, it's object-oriented.

Comment: @BoltClock: What is the difference between being objective and Object oriented?

Comment: @Krishnan: I think the word objective here is just part of the name Objective-C and doesn't mean anything special itself.

Comment: @BoldClock: The difference is Objective-C is dynamically typed and C++ is statically typed. And Objective-C++ has it both.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

C++ is Bjarne Stroustroup's language based on adding classes and metaprogramming to C in such a way that puts most additional work into the compiler, and relies on least possible effort at runtime.

Objective-C is Brad Cox's language based on adding a SmallTalk-style dynamic message-passing runtime library to C, with a small amount of syntax addition to make it easier to use.

Objective-C++ is, to put it bluntly, what you get when you add the Objective-C runtime and syntax to C++. It has its limitations (e.g. you can't create an Objective-C subclass of a C++ class or vice versa, and Objective-C doesn't like C++ namespaces) but allows you to use C++ classes from Objective-C objects and vice versa.

You can use Objective-C++ in iPhone development. What this means practically is that you could write an application whose object model was entirely C++, where the controller layer would need to interface to Objective-C in order to use the Cocoa Touch APIs.

Comment: I'll also add that Objective-C is a *strict* superset of C, while C++ is not. https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B

Comment: Objective-C++ is a great way to make use of STL templates like vector and map - for which there are no good, low-cost analogs in Cocoa.

Comment: )Can give any sample code that contains both Objective-C  and C++.

Comment: @Madan have a look at the ObjC integration code in CATCH. https://github.com/philsquared/Catch

Comment: @StephenFurlani - a small correction, Objective C begun as a strict superset of C, but it is no longer the case, especially with Objective C 2.0 and the newer Clang extensions (which is the de facto Objective C pushed by Apple).

Answer (score 5):

C++ and Objective C were/are two different approaches to adding object orientation to C. Current objective C compilers also accept C++ as input, so you can build a program with some files written in Objective-C and other files written in C++. When C++ is used this way, it's often called Objective-C++.

Comment: Okay, Thank you. Can we use C++ for iPhone development

Comment: @Madan: Yes. You need to use at least a little Objective C where your code interfaces with the iPhone's built-in libraries, but you can use C++ for pretty much everything else.

Answer (score 0):

1) C++ is a language derived from C that adds Object Orientation (OO) amongst other features. *
2) Objective-C is a language derived from C that adds Object Orientation (OO) amongst other features. *
3) Objective-C++ is Objective-C that you can use C++ classes with.

You CAN use C++ for iPhone development but you will need "some" Objective-C code to interface with the iPhone libraries.

(*) Though they both try to solve the same problem they do it quite differently.  There is some information about the differences on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Philosophical_differences_between_Objective-C_and_C.2B.2B) and I'm sure you can use google to find more.

Answer (score -4):

> You CAN use C++ for iPhone development but you will need "some" Objective-C code to interface with the iPhone libraries.

This will very likely give you code and possibly memory bloat. As you know, iOS programming should be a lean as possible: minimize both the library size and runtime memory needs. iOS programming and runtime environments are also highly optimized for Objective C.

Pure ObjC is much better than C++ for iOS. Unless you're trying to use existing large C++ code base it will probably be better to re-write from scratch. Nearly all of the C++ STL have analogs in the iOS frameworks, often easier to use, and highly optimized by Apple.
Learn Objective C memory management, get familiar with the frameworks and go for it.

Comment: correction: if you use both languages very well and binary size and memory consumption are your top priorities, c++ will typically be the smaller in binary size *and* memory consumption. added bonus: c++ programs will generally execute faster than objc programs. don't bother rewriting your existing c++ programs as objc programs.