# Objective-C++ for iOS development

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, objective-c++

Is it possible to use Objective-C++ for iOS application (iPhone, iPad, iPod touch) development?

Are there any examples and source code on the Internet?

Comment: I'm wondering what draws you to C++? Some iOS games use a bit of C++ but it's really not touched much on the iPhone, as Cocoa-Touch makes most of the C++ advantages redundant. I did find this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804219/what-is-the-difference-between-c-objective-c-and-objective-c/3804297#3804297 The marked answer is very helpful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using ObjC++ is quite easy.
You have to declare source files with extension .mm. It will make compiler treat them as ObjC++. The same with headers: use the .hh extension.

There is another option: go to target settings and set Compile Sources As  to Objective-C++.

That's all. No additional work is necessary.

Some notes: if you want to develop a native iOS app, then use Objective C. It will save a lot of time.
But in some cases using C++ is more appropriate. E.g. for cross-platform development. So you use only a little bit of Objective C for iPhone or Java for Android just to glue your code with environment. Everything else in C++. I use this for my cross-platform game development.

Another case is performance: Objective C is principally slower then C++. However it is only noticeable during method calls (in ObjC it is called messaging).

Comment: For cross platform purposes, it tends to break down that you have the view class purely in Objective-C, the controller entirely in Objective-C but compiled as Objective-C++ so that it can call out to a model written entirely in C++. You can ameliorate all of Objective-C's dynamic dispatch calls by hooking straight into the runtime since you can get the current C function pointer for any method, but it's ugly and doesn't fit the object-oriented model properly.

Comment: @Tommy you're absolutely right. But I've told that I use only the minimal amount of Objective C to have ability to bind to the system (for example touch events or CAEAGLLayer to bind OpenGL). But I don't use Objective C in C++ classes. Just C++ in Objective C to have the minimal interface with the system.

Comment: So the whole engine is in C++ but it has some platform specific classes.

Comment: I think that's probably smart; I guess the more native GUI you want, the more you get pushed into native language territory — so games tend to be at the shallow end. I went to a thing at Nokia a few weeks ago (ie, shortly before the Nokia-Microsoft announcement that effectively outlaws C/C++ for future Nokia phones) and they strongly advocated exactly what you're suggesting.

Comment: Yes, this is only valid for games. Don't see any reason to use C++ on iPhone or Android  if you're not developing game.

Comment: Focusing on a slowdown in messaging in Objective-C can be a bit of premature optimization: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/performance-comparisons-of-common-operations-iphone-edition.html .  On the original iPhone, messages are roughly as slow as a floating point division, so they're by no means the bottleneck the vast majority of the time.

Comment: @Brad Larson: well it's slower for more then 2 times then C++ virtual method call (and I suppose much much slower then non-virtual call)... Though I didn't say that this is the real bottle neck, it's just slower. The language selection is more like the question of app architecture. BTW thanks for the link, really interesting =)

Comment: @Max - If you want more quality reading, check out [Bill Bumgarner's four-part series on how Objective-C message sending works](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/12/18/objc_msgsend-part-1-the-road-map/) (including the hand-tuned assembly behind it).

Comment: @Brad Larson   thanks, already saw that. And also ObjC implementation source code  from here http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437.1/ :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Take a look at the samples and new file templates that Apple provides.

Comment: I would love to know where these templates are. :-)

Comment: @NoEvilPeople For the record, here's one >:)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/aurioTouch/History/History.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007770-RevisionHistory-DontLinkElementID_1