# Compiling/Running C++ code on iPhone

Tags: c++, objective-c, linux, ios4

I have recently created an Asteroids game/app for one of my CS classes with openGL, GLU and C++ for Linux. The teacher told me that if I get it to run on the iPhone he would give me extra credit. I have been looking around and I think I have to develop/port it to Objective C using the iPhone Development Kit. My questions are:

- Would this be easy to port?
- Can I install the Development Kit on Windows, or Linux (I do not have a Mac).
- Is there an alternative way (shortcut) to maybe emulate Linux binaries on the iPhone?

I have not tried anything yet, because I would like to know first what you guys think. You do not have to tell me exactly what to do, but I would highly appreciate if you would point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: First and foremost - you can't install the iOS SDK on anything but a Mac. [C++ works fine on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090968/objective-c-for-ios-development), but you would need to spend a lot of time adapting your code. (For one, your OpenGL code would have to be rewritten to use only functions available in OpenGL ES.)

Comment: Even if you can figure out how to generate binaries on something other than a Mac, unless the iPhone is jailbroken you need a certificate from Apple to deploy the program to an iPhone and Apple charges money for that. Also, if your OpenGL code uses immediate mode (things like glVertex3f) then, no, that's not supported. Immediate mode is not really useful for real graphics work and it's been removed from recent versions of OpenGL, including OpenGL ES on the iPhone.

Comment: @PeterSobot That's good to know! I implemented all of my openGL functions in different files (I can also run the app in Windows), so I would just have to create a new library for OpenGL ES. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @bames53 Unfortunately I am using glVertex a lot. I will have to find a way to re-implement the methods that use outdated openGL methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you don't want to port your program into another language. You CAN use SDL2, it seems pretty stable and it works on iOS (iPhone/iPad/iPod Touch). All you would have to do is change your code and then play around with the controls. You'll have to clone the Mercurial repo from http://hg.libsdl.org/. It will come with a README.iOS file, in which describes how the port works and some other details. I am not sure if it has multi-touch support yet, I have not tested it.

Also, you can use immediate mode on the iPhone, you just can't use OpenGL ES 2 if you do that. All you have to do is make a context for OpenGL ES 1.1.

And you WILL need a Mac, or perhaps you could get a Hackintosh to compile your code and then run it with a jailbroken iPod/iPhone/iPad.

**NOTE:**
I believe I have heard of some people compiling their code on a Hackintosh and then submitting it to the app store from a Mac within an Apple store.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Miguel! I will look into this information you have provided me with.