# C++ functions in Objective C

Tags: c++, objective-c

I am getting a bit confused how to call C++ functions in Objective C.

I've declared my functions as:

```
void InitializeSearchRegistration();
```

In the header file in between the interface and end. I've then defined it in my mm file as:

```
void InitializeServiceRegistration()
{
}
```

What I am struggling with is how to define it as public to ensure other classes can see it. I've tried public but get an error. Usually C++ methods have to be declared in a class block.

Any advice would be great.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090968/objective-c-for-ios-development

Answer (score 1):

You can't add C++ member functions to an Objective-C class using Objective-C++. You should consider redesigning your class to either have a totally C++ interface (in which case it should be a C++ `class` or `struct`) or a totally Objective-C interface (in which case it should define ObjC class and instance methods, not C++ member functions).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about this, the first is to combine C++ and Objective C into another language, called Objective C++. The other is to communicate over plain C functions.